# CancellationException silent Exception inside CoroutineScope, does not crash/exit the application

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines, cancellation

I've been studying Kotlin Coroutines.
I figure it out that when one cancels a Coroutine, it is thrown a CancellationException, but that does not crash / exit application.
e.g.

```
    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        coroutineScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    }
```

Then I have this code:

```
            coroutineScope.launch {
                doSomethingFor10Seconds()
            }
```

If I press Android home button while the Coroutine is executing, it will cancel the Coroutine, and won't crash the app, it won't even log the Exception on logcat.

But if I add a try..catch block, it will catch the exception, when I press the Android home button, while the Coroutine is executing:

```
            coroutineScope.launch {
                try {
                    doSomething()
                } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
```

I've tried to check, if this was something implemented for this specific exception: CancellationException, but when I did the experiment, it did crash/exit the app.

```
    private fun throwCancellationException(){
        throw CancellationException()
    }
```

Then I called it on the onCreateView() from the Fragment lifecycle:

```
throwCancellationException()
```

That crashes the app.
Only when I surround with try..catch, it ceases to crash.

```
        try {
            throwCancellationException()
        } catch (e: CancellationException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

But if I call the CancellationException inside the Coroutine Scope (launch builder function), no crash, no log in logcat:

```
            coroutineScope.launch {
                doSomethingFor10Seconds()
                throwCancellationException()
            }
```

DOES NOT CRASH!

And if I call another exception, like IllegalStateException(), inside CoroutineScope:

```
    private fun throwIllegalStateException(){
        throw IllegalStateException()
    }
```

```
            coroutineScope.launch {
                doSomethingFor10Seconds()
                throwIllegalStateException()
            }
```

CRASHES!

I figure it out, that some combination of the CancellationException, and being executed on the CoroutineScope / Job. I've tried to get into the Kotlin Source Code to understand how this magic happens, but I couldn't figure it out.
Anyone could explain me, how this Exception does not crash the app in the CoroutineScope?
And how could I implement a custom exception in Kotlin, that does not crash/exit the app (I would like to learn about that, if can anyone help me with that)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CancellationException` is used internally as a way to cancel coroutines. You're not supposed to catch them or, if you do, you should rethrow them. More info in the [official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#cancellation-and-exceptions).

Comment: I think you need to dig into the `CoroutineScope.launch` function implementation to see how the `CancellationException` is handled.